# Getting error in changing co-ordinates of imageview in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner to android. I want to slide a slidebar in a horizontal linear layout but when I run the code, the application ends giving error `FallingBall keeps stopping`

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="72"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slideBar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/leftBut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/left_but"
                android:onClick="hitLeft"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/rightBut"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_but"
                android:onClick="hitRight"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My java file is like this:

```
    package com.example.fallingball;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView s = findViewById(R.id.slideBar);
float x = s.getX();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}


void hitLeft(View view){
    x--;
    s.setX(30);
}

void hitRight(View view){
    x++;
    s.setX(40);
}
}
```

Note: `leftBut` and `rightBut` are two Image button and I have copied the images to the drawable folder so if you are trying this code on your system, make sure you adjust this else it will show you Image not found or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity.java you should initialize your value into onCreate() method

```
ImageView s;
float x;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    s = findViewById(R.id.slideBar);
    x = s.getX();
}
```

Comment: Well, this worked in a limit... Earlier my application was crashing just when you open it but now it does not happen. Now it does not crash until you press the buttons... But I got the solution to it...

Comment: Was your problem completely solved or does the application crash when you press the button?

Comment: When I did what you suggested, the problem of application crashing as soon as opening it was solved and it started working. The application crashed only when pressing any of the two buttons... Thankyou

Comment: Perfect.I'm glad accept my answer :) I now work to second problem

Comment: I solved the second problem...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my own mistake. The thing what hossein answered earlier was right but the application was still crashing. Actually the problem was coming that I was triggering the methods `hitLeft` and `hitRight` which were not initialized as `public`. That was the mistake and now it is working alright...